# Type '{ children: string; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IModalProps'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, office-ui-fabric

This code:

```js
import { Modal } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Modal";
import * as React from "react";

export interface ISignInFormProps {
  showModal: boolean;
}

const SignInForm = () => {
  return <Modal>Hello</Modal>;
};

export default SignInForm;
```

Produces the following error:

> (9,11): Type '{ children: string; }' has no properties in common with
>   type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IModalProps'.

[image]

This CodePen doesn't display any error - https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/aMmzKq?editors=0010

What is the cause of the problem and how can it be resolved?

Comment: Maybe you are missing a require prop?

Comment: @MoshFeu A bit new to this. Could you explain?

Comment: It seems to not be relevant :( forget it..

Comment: You are not passing `IModalProps`. What is your `IModalProps`?

Comment: @FortyTwo But this works fine - `const SignInForm = () => { return <Modal /> };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set *any* children, not JSX Element (e.g. `<div>Hello</div>`), not string (as shown in your code).

A known issue with using Fabric with TypeScript 3.3 : https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/issues/7874

## Fix

Two ways:

- Move to TypeScript 3.2 if you want to use Fabric for now
- Alternatively add a `fix.d.ts` with the contents : https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/issues/7874#issuecomment-462432481

`fix.d.ts`:

```
declare module 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Modal' {
 const Modal: React.StatelessComponent<IModalProps>;
}
```

Comment: where to add this file? I mean in which folder? And how to include this file anywhere? Do we need to import this file somewhere or just creating this file anywhere in folder is enough? Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 3):

We have a fix for this issue. TypeScript 3.x exposed a typing error with our styled utility's return value, which wasn't using React's StatelessComponent type and therefore did not have the `children` prop. The PR is [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/pull/8189) and should be available in our next nightly release.